# Meteor - Angular6 AOT production build throws error on Angular-Tree-Component package

Tags: meteor, tree, treeview, angular6, angular-meteor

I am working on Meteor - Angular 6. We are using [angular-tree-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-component) package. It's working fine in development. 
While doing the production build, we are facing the below error

> node_modules/angular-tree-component/dist/components/tree-node.component.ngfactory.ts (13, 21):
>
> Cannot find module './tree-node-wrapper.component.ngfactory'

```
 Base Code:
   https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor-base

 Installed Package Version: 
   "angular-tree-component": "^8.2.0"
```

#### Steps to replicate the issue:

1. Download the Base code ( Urigo angular-meteor base )
2. Install all the dependent packages ( meteor npm install / npm install )
3. Do basic configure `angular-tree-component` package
4. Once basic flow works, run `meteor build ./output  --architecture os.linux.x86_64`
5. You can able to get the error

> Note: Before these steps, you should install these packages globally `meteor` and `node`

It would be helpful if anyone provide solution for this bug.